# Deep link redirection with the ionic plugin Deeplinking

Tags: ionic3, ios-universal-links, deeplink

I used the Deeplinks plugin and the Universal links for a native ionic application. By clicking on the link: `<h1> <a href="aefinfo://example.fr/depeche/?id=598007"> link to AEF </a> </ h1>` it sends you back to the application and on the page depeche n ° 598007. So it works, anyway, if we click on the link above and the person does not have the application installed, I find myself with a blank page. I would like to know how to detect if the person does not have the application installed and redirect to my site, https://example.fr
Thanks for your help